# 'SimpleZipcode' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which includes 2 variables - city and state.  I'm trying to identify the zip codes and then create a new variable named zipcode and add that into my dataframe.  I have this code:

```
def get_zipcode(city, state):
    search = SearchEngine()
    result = search.by_city_and_state(city=city.lower(), state=state.lower())

    if result and result[0] and result[0]['zip_code']:
        return result[0].zipcode
    else:
        return(0)
```

However, when I try just a simple print statement to check or my code to add the zipcode variable into my dataframe I'm receiving the error: 'SimpleZipcode' object is not subscriptable.

`print(get_zipcode("chicago", "il"))` is the check code I'm using and after that I'm using

```
# add zipcode column
df['zip_code'] = df[['City', 'State']].apply(
    lambda x: get_zipcode(
        x['City'].upper(),
        x['State'].upper()
    ),
    axis=1
)
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: I think something could be wrong with your installation. Because even if there were somehow no results returned, there would still be an empty list in `result`. How did you install? When you first ran `search = SearchEngine()` were some files downloaded?

Comment: no - when i first ran the search engine part there was not.  Even when i did the original import as from uszipcode import Zipcode
from uszipcode import SearchEngine I did not have anything download.  Would there be something else I need to run?  Also - I'm running in Colab and for some reason today when I run all my other code even my graphs aren't displaying.  Not sure if the issues could be related.

Comment: Oh ya bc it's Colab is probably the issue. I don't know much about that, but probably it's going to require some add'l setup to get this module to work -- if it's even possible on Colab...